how to make a color see through
Is there any way I can keep this green but also can see what is beneath/under the green glass. I tried all option available in Illustratror,but nothing works. I need help  :'(


Multiply blending mode should work. But only applied to the green circle itself.
You have to make sure that there isn't anything blocking the green though. It looks like you might have a white circle below the green circle.
So make a copy of the green circle and subtract it from the white circle using pathfinder so there's free passage for the green color.

You are too intelligent for this time!!   :O U r so right. That imbecile designer (me) didnt notice that white fill under the green circle! I tried so many hours to figure it out!! Thank you so much. I am eternally grateful.

You could set the green object to Multiply mode in the Appearance panel.
Here's an example


Thank you so much. I did something stupid. A white fill was under the green circle. I forget abt it. Thank you Billy.
